# replace column with variable for left join

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to replace left join with variable i am using with code.
can this be done? so instead of

```
LEFT JOIN tbl_campaigns ON
          tbl_creatives.fk_s_id_tbl_campaigns = tbl_campaigns.s_id
```

I need to have

```
LEFT JOIN tbl_campaigns ON
          '100' = tbl_campaigns.s_id
```

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: LEFT JOIN tbl_campaigns ON
          tbl_creatives.fk_s_id_tbl_campaigns = tbl_campaigns.s_id AND  tbl_campaigns.s_id = '100' ?

Answer (score 0):

The `join` condition can be any boolean condition.  This includes constants, subqueries, and quite complex expressions.

In general, equijoins (equality conditions) perform better than other types of conditions.

In your case, if you know that `'100'` is in the table, you don't need a `left join`.